# Enabling multi threaded downloading in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, download

I want to create a chrome extension which can enable multi thread downloading of files. Does chrome expose some API which can be used to read file streams using javascript?

I was wondering why does chrome by default not support multi threaded downloading? Also if there are any ways of doing the same right now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html) (as of now, available on the dev channel only) seems to support your request. Each invocation of the [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#method-download) method constitutes a download of its own inside a separate thread (or process, for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

Look at Metalink Downloader: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metalink-downloader/jnpljlobbiggcdikagmiepniibjdinap

Metalink Downloader can set 10 simultaneous connections to download from one url.